# Taking array of pointers as a parameter, then assigning it to a field

Tags: c++, pointers

I have the following:

```
class foo {
private:
  bar * x[];
public:
  foo(bar * x[]);
};

foo::foo(bar * x[]) {
  this->x = x;
}
```

As far as I understand, `x` is a pointer to a pointer to the first element of a `bar` array (both the field `x` and the parameter `x`). I must be wrong, though, because this code does not work. I get the following error:

`In constructor 'foo::foo(bar**)': error: incompatible types in assignment of 'bar**' to 'bar* [0]'`

How do I resolve this issue? What am I not understanding correctly?

Note: As you've probably assumed, bar is a class and not some placeholder for a primitive type.

EDIT:

My goal is to do this elsewhere in the program:

```
bar a[2];
bar b0 = bar(), b1 = bar();
a[0] = &b0;
a[1] = &b1;
bar * x[] = &a;
foo f = foo(x);
```

How would I achieve that? Also, isn't `bar * x[] = &a;` equivalent to `bar ** x = &a`, where `&a` is equivalent to `&(&a[0])`? What am I not understanding here?

Comment: `x` is not a pointer, it's an array!

Comment: `bar * x[];` in private size is `0` if not given, its zero size array not pointer to pointer, *declaration in function parameters and normal declaration are diffrent*

Comment: But arrays are themselves pointers to their first element, no?

Comment: @Intredasting: No, they are not. Your confusion is caused by the fact that arrays can implicitly decay into pointers to their first elements.

Comment: Ahhhhhhh, I think I get it now. So I'm trying to assign an array of pointers to the first element of an array of pointers... just as the compiler says I am! Thanks heaps. I'm going to change my implementation of this, I think, to use some some custom implementation of std::vector ... the only reason I can't in the first place is because I'm using an Arduino :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
bar * x[];
```

`x` is an array of `bar` pointers (not sure why you didn't declare the array size).

For example,

```
int a[] = { 11, 22, 33 };
int b[3];

b = a;  // Error
```

You can not assign one array to another array. You have to programatically copy the individual array elements to the other. To be able to do that, you need the size of the source, destination arrays.

Comment: Of course you *can* assign modern arrays, though (`std::array`).

Comment: I didn't declare the array size because the array size isn't known. I want to take the array of pointers as a parameter.

Comment: @Intredasting if you don't know the size of the array, then you have to keep track of its size separately. Or use an `std::vector`.